# Is there an easy way to make gcc omit crtbegin.o/crtend.o?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Aside from using `-nostdlib` and linking `crt1.o -lc -lgcc` yourself, is there any easy way to prevent gcc from linking `crtbegin[S].o` and `crtend[S].o`? These files are not that large, but I'm playing around with making small binaries, and would like to remove the useless C++ support code that's not needed for C programs. (Presumably, gcc links them even for C programs in case you're using a C++ library with global object variables. I'll spare everyone the rant about how it should be generating safe one-time initialization calls everywhere the global object is referenced in C++ modules rather than initializing global objects prior to `main`...)

I wouldn't be opposed to hacking the gcc `specs` file to make linking of the C++ support files conditional on such-and-such, but I'm not sure how I would do that. Perhaps there's already a nice way?

Comment: I believe they're needed for `__attribute__ ((constructor))` (and `destructor`) functions, too.  (and I'm far from a C++ expert, but I'm told that to conform to the standard, global constructors there have to happen before `main()` is called.)

Comment: @caf: I was under the impression that the C++ standard specifies that the constructors are called at an unspecified time between program invocation and the first time the object is used (and of course in unspecified order, aside from cases where one object references another and thus invokes the "first time it's used"). Do you have a reference to the contrary?

Comment: Probably an "egg-sucking teach", but have you tried using `gcc` to compile and going straight to your systems linker (probably `ld`) for the actual link step so that you have greater control over the link?

Comment: @Charles: I know I can do that, but then I have to go find the standard library files and library path myself. It's slightly more painful than `gcc -nostdlib`.

Comment: I'm currently using the `specs` file hacking to skip linking those files; wrote a gcc wrapper in shell, like `exec /usr/bin/gcc --specs /usr/lib/gcc/specs-no-c++ "$@"`. For me this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gcc -wrapper sh,-c,'z= ; for i ; do [ "$z" ] || set -- ; z=1 ;
    case "$i" in *crtbegin*.o|*crtend*.o) ;; *) set -- "$@" "$i" ;; esac ;
    done ; exec "$0" "$@"'
```

Comment: can someone explain what is happening in the above script?

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7: The `-wrapper` option gets gcc to invoke external commands it runs via a wrapper program. The wrapper program is a shell script which drops any arguments matching `*crtbegin*.o` or `*crtend*.o` before invoking the requested command. It's just written inline on the command line rather than saving the script to a file.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need the `-nostartfiles` option.  That's what I need for embedded stuff anyways.

Comment: That's a good start (no pun intended), but it also omits `crt1.o` which contains the `_start` entry point.

Comment: @R..: I am sure you could setup the ENTRYPOINT in the linker script.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do it like that, but that's a lot worse than finding the path to `crt1.o` and using the `gcc` command line to link. Basically I was looking for the closest thing to a portable way to get gcc not to link in unnecessary stuff, and the answers seems to be that there is none.

Comment: @R..: But why would you have to still link crt1.o?

Comment: `crt1.o` is not C++ support junk. It's the normal entry point for C code which extracts `argc`, `argv`, and a pointer to the environment from the initial state given to the program by the kernel, and uses that to call `exit(main(argc,argv));`

Comment: @R..: Right, forgot about those  :)

Comment: By the way, `gcc -print-file-name=crt1.o` will give you the pathname of `crt1.o` which you can use to re-add it after passing `-nostartfiles`.